# Segoe UI Symbol emoji character not displaying in colour on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, colors, character, winrt-xaml

On Windows Phone 8, the following xaml displays an emoji character in colour:

```
<TextBlock 
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
    TextOptions.DisplayColorEmoji="True"
    Text="smilie's unicode that I don't have off-hand"/>
```

However, when this code is run on Windows Phone 8.1, the emoji's background colour is unfilled. That is, it's not got a yellow background; the emoji's outlines are only coloured.

So, for example, it looks like this in Windows Phone 8.0:

[image]

But it looks like this in Windows Phone 8.1:

[image]

I've seen that Windows Phone 8.1. introduces a new "IsColorFontEnabled" property. I don't know if this fixes it on 8.1, but I do know in order to use it, I must migrate the app to 8.1, which I don't want to as I want to keep 8.0 backward compatibility for the time being.

So, is there a way to have a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app that uses a color emoji, that would also display it in colour on Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, We can use **IsColorFontEnabled** in TextBlock to display emoji with colour. **IsColorFontEnabled** is type of Boolean, and it's default value is false(means don't display colour). But if you set `FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol",` the colour emoji also **don't display**.

The sample code like this:

```
<TextBlock IsColorFontEnabled ="True" Text="I am a TextBlock "/>
```

And If you don't want to re-target your project to Windows Phone 8.1, Just remove **FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"** , like this:

```
<TextBlock TextOptions.DisplayColorEmoji="True" Text="I am a TextBlock "/>
```

Because if you set fontfamily to `Segoe UI Symbol`, the emoji will be displayed as **character**.

Comment: Yes, but I want the xaml to work in Windows Phone 8.0 too. That property is only available if I retarget my app to Windows Phone 8.1 only. I'd like a solution that works on both 8.0 and 8.1 simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But, if I remove the FontFamily, how do I make sure the font used is "Segoe UI Symbol"? By setting that as the FontFamily for the TextBlock's parent?

Comment: You can use Run in TextBlock. emoji with no fontfamily setting, other chars with fontfamily of "Segoe UI Symbol"

Comment: Not having a FontFamily, but using the unicode for the Segoe UI Symbol I was after would display it correctly on both WP 8.0 and WP 8.1. Thanks!