# some emoji characters are not displaying in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, textblock, emoji

I am developing a  WP messaging application which will receive messages from other other clients.

I am facing issue with displaying emojis sent from iPhone version of the app .

for eg: i received the following message in  `☝` (utf8) my app . Its rendering like below .
[image]

The same text is renederd properly in WP Whatsapp.

[image]

I am using `RichTextBox` to display the message . I tried with the `Textblock` also, but its also giving the same output.

Also tried with options suggested in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011092/segoe-ui-symbol-emoji-character-not-displaying-in-colour-on-windows-phone-8-1) answers. Tried luck in Both silverlight and WinRt . but still i am getting the issue.

How can i make it displaying properly (Like whatsapp)?

I hope someone will give me the leads to understand how whatsapp is displaying this text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that in the second screenshot, custom glyphs are being used, rather than just using the built in emojis

Comment: thanks Rowland .what does glyphs means ? Is it images ?  So whats app might keeping images for the extra  emoji s  which are not available in WP.  The problem i am facing is some emojis sent from iPhone is not displaying properly in my app .But whatsapp does